# Prewarn users that question may be off topic based on tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, vote-to-close, off-topic

I recently came across the [appstore-approval](/questions/tagged/appstore-approval) tag and noticed this in the wiki:

> App store approval is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions marked with this tag concern the approval process of an iOS or OS X application by Apple before the application is added to the App Store. **If this applies to your question, it is very likely off-topic**.

In an attempt to educate users and help with the close-vote review list, would it be possible and feasible to add:

- The ability to mark tags as off-topic
- A warning when a question is asked with one of these tags explaining that their question is unlikely to be answered on SO.
- Questions with one or more of these tags require fewer votes to close with the tag effectively counting as one or more votes.

**Pros**

- Off-topic questions could either be

  - Stopped before they are asked
  - Rephrased and reconsidered so that they are on topic.
- Users learn what kind of questions are off topic implicitly. (Few seem to read faq or how-to-ask)
- There would be fewer new questions cluttering the ever-growing close vote reviews.
- Existing questions in the close vote review list could be handled more quickly.

**Cons**

- Users posing new questions may simply circumvent the warning by removing the offending tag.
- Existing questions with these tags would be left in an indeterminate state.
- Requires existing off-topic tags to be flagged as such.

Comment: Off-topic tags shouldn't even exist in the first place, along with their questions.

Comment: The problem is that the questions *do* exist though. Users don't learn that they were off topic until they're closed because nobody reads the [faq], [ask] or tag wikis

Comment: If a tag is known to be off topic then why keep the tag around in the first place?

Comment: Then an addition to this might be: "And stop further use of these tags"

Comment: @JoeW: Until the questions get fully cleaned up -- reviewed and either the tags corrected or the question closed -- it can actually be better to keep the tag as a marker. Just destroying the tag sort of releases the questions into the wild and makes those that truly are off-topic harder to find.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes I understand that and the goal should be to clear up the tags and kill them rather then provide a warning saying the post may be off topic based on the off topic tags.

Comment: Agreed, @JoeW; I'm working as fast as I can! :)