# Identify tags that tend to be associated with off-topic/problematic questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, search, question-quality, analytics

Anecdotally, I've noticed that a few tags on a site I frequently visit tend to be associated with questions that are off-topic (e.g., > 70% of questions with that tag have been closed).

Is there a systematic way to find such tags?  For instance, is there a way to find all tags where most questions with that tag have been closed?  Or, a way to find all tags where most questions with that tag have a total vote score that is negative?  I can't figure out how to do this using search, but maybe there's some clever way to do it with SEDE.

Motivation: I want to identify tags that could most benefit from having a tag wiki excerpt that provides clearer guidance on the site's expectations.  If I notice that most questions with that tag have been closed, I can then write a tag wiki excerpt that clarifies our policy and scope.  But is there a way to find such tags in the first place?

Related: [Tags with high frequency of off-topic/wrong-site questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228958/160917) asks what to do with such tags, but not how to identify them; [Prewarn users that question may be off topic based on tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212071/160917) proposes some specific changes to how the site works for such tags, but I'm asking how to identify them, not suggesting any changes to site functioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer these questions:

> - Is there a way to find all tags where most questions with that tag have been closed

- Find all tags where most questions with that tag have a total vote score that is negative

with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/724476):

```sql
select tagname
     , [closed]
     , [total]
     , [negscore] 
     , (cast([closed] as decimal) / total) * 100  as [% closed]
     , (cast([negscore] as decimal) / total) * 100  as [% negative score]
from (
select t.tagname
     , count(*) [closed]
     , sum(case when p.score < 0 then 1 else 0 end) [negscore]
     , t.count [total]
from tags t
inner join posttags pt on  t.id = pt.tagid
inner join posts p on p.id = pt.postid
where exists (select * 
              from  posthistory ph 
              where pt.postid = ph.postid and posthistorytypeid = 10)
and count > 1
group by t.tagname
       , t.count
having count(*) < count

) as data
order by [% closed] desc
```

Notice that I filtered out tags with just 1 question. Be aware that this query only take non-deleted questions (and therefor tags) into account. The main reason is that the table `posttags` doesn't include deleted posts. In theory you could go over the rows in the `postwithdeleted` table for a specific tag if you need stats for the now deleted posts as well.

When run today on Stack Overflow your result will be:
[image: SEDE query results]

Keep in mind that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday.